# How do I create a virtual raster in QGIS combining single-band raster layers and a multi-band raster?

Tags: qgis, raster, multi-band, virtual-raster

I have a raster with 21 bands. I also have 12 other raster layers with a single band each. I want to create a virtual raster combining the multi-band raster and the single-band raster layers, resulting in a single raster with 33 (21 + 12) bands. I have included an image to show what I am trying to do (possibly somewhat redundant).

However, when I try creating a virtual raster in QGIS, the result is a raster with 13 bands. The first band of the resulting raster layer only contains the first band of the multi-band raster, and the other bands are the single-band raster layers. When creating the virtual raster, I do not see an option to solve this. Or should I use other tools, e.g. the raster calculator?

[image: Example]

Comment: It's a pain, but you can translate each band of the 21 band raster to a VRT (in Processing Toolbox - GDAL - Raster conversion - Translate (convert format) tool. You need to run Translate 21 times, each time specifying which band in the Additional command-line parameters box with `-b N` where `N` is the band number to convert (1-21). Then building the 33 band virtual raster from the 21 new single band VRTs and the 12 existing single band rasters.  I've not found another way apart from writing a GDAL python script.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the response! That is a pain indeed, however... I will probably just write a script. It would be nice to have a QGIS plugin for this, though.